# add secondary .ts file that gets build as extra .js file into dist alongside app

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, nomachine-nx

I would like to compile Angular as usual + an extra .ts file that gets output as its own .js file in the dist folder.

What I have been doing is running 2 npm scripts

```
nx build client-extension && npm run client-extension:injector
```

But it gives a lot of extra hassle, also I cannot let the first command 'watch' cause than the second would never fire. I'm aware there are options like custom webpack configs etc.

But isn't there a simpler way to tell NX/Angular, to compile the app + an extra file?
It works with angular worker files (they become separate .js file), so was thinking of abusing that logic, but that's also not very nice.

this is my current project.json:

```
{
  "name": "client-extension",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "candlejumper",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/client-extension/src",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/client-extension",
        "index": "apps/client-extension/src/index.html",
        "browser": "apps/client-extension/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/client-extension/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["apps/client-extension/src/favicon.ico", "apps/client-extension/src/assets", "apps/client-extension/src/manifest.json"],
        "styles": ["apps/client-extension/src/style/styles.scss"]
      },
```

So basically, I would like to add an option to the project.json, like

```
{
  "extraFiles": ["./my-second-entry.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`styles` and `scripts` section](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration) of the `angular.json` file does not only support plain strings. You have the option here to specify what bundles **@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser** should be generating, and if they should be loaded immediately in the index.html.

```
"build": {
  ...
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/xxx",
    "index": "xxx/src/index.html",
    "main": "xxx/src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "xxx/src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "xxx/tsconfig.app.json",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "assets": [
      "xxx/src/favicon.ico",
      "xxx/src/assets",
      "xxx/src/web.config"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "xxx/src/styles.scss",
      {
        "input": "xxx/src/styles/solarized-dark",
        "inject": false,
        "bundleName": "solarized-dark"
      }
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "xxx/scripts/some-script.js",
      {
        "input": "xxx/scripts/path/to/some-typescript.ts",
        "bundleName": "other-scripts",
        "inject": true
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/styles-and-scripts) a demo with the [commit that applies this feature](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/styles-and-scripts/commit/6f0e0f454172b1539a3bec7fa1760ba537f77dd9).

Demo:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, you don't need the file extension (css/js) in the bundleName.

Comment: Update: it only seems to work because your .ts file is empty. It is not being transpiled into JS

Comment: Hi. Strange... The last image demonstrates that the message ends up on the `window`

Comment: No, it seems that the `scripts` section only accepts js files. According to [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17125) it's not supposed to accept `ts` files. I assume if you want to lazy-load some typescript files, you're supposed to use `import('../../other/script').then(m => m.OtherClass)` which gives you types all the way

Comment: Thanks for looking into it :) I'm using it as an 'inject'  script for a chrome extension. So it also shouldn't be imported in the 'main' app, not even the same index.html.. So that makes it pretty unusual maybe. Reason for trying to get into one project.json, is because they interact a lot and don't want to manually run a separate compiler for this 1 file everytime an interface or something changes..  Guess its back to an extra webpack.config file to make it happen :(

Comment: Hi, there's an NX executor you can use too :-) It's called [`nx:run-commands`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap-snippets/project.json#L8) Just pass a tsconfig to `tsc` with the file you need to compile to javascript. This way it's totally seperated from your main project and not tree-shaken either.

Comment: run-commands doesnt seem to understand 'watch'.. Its for absolute start/end but not in between